# Run a function constantly

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport, inview

I'm using the excellent [inView](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview) plugin to check if an element is visible in the viewport, using setInterval, but the function only runs once and only when the element IS visible, not otherwise (should run else statement).

```
var checkViewport = setInterval(function() {
    $('#colorbox').on('inview', function(event, visible) {
      if (visible) {
        console.log('YES');
      } else {
        console.log('NO');
      }
    });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: You're rebinding the event every iteration of the interval.

Comment: What is it that you expect to happen upon each interval?

Comment: @Pointy I need to check visibility on each interval.

Comment: @Nimbuz the plugin you're using already runs its own interval timer. You just need to bind the event handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind the event once, and check a separate variable. Try this:

```
var isVisible = false;

$('#colorbox').on('inview', function(event, visible) {
    isVisible = visible;
});

var checkViewport = setInterval(function() {
    if (isVisible) {
        console.log('YES');
    } else {
        console.log('NO');
    }
}, 5000);
```

You can structure this differently to make sure `isVisible` isn't a global variable and can be accessed by the `setInterval` still as well.

Answer (score 1):

The code in your example only binds an event when the element's in the viewport. You're not actually executing anything, just repeatedly binding an event.

I would suggest instead checking the element `colorbox` every interval, then logging to the console whether the `colorbox` is visible.

**Source (HTML DOM and JavaScript):**

```
var checkViewport = setInterval(function() {
    myColorBox = document.getElementById("colorbox");
      if (myColorBox.style.visibility == "visible") {
        console.log('YES');
      } else {
        console.log('NO');
      }
    });
}, 5000);
```